# LLamaindex index.storage_context.persist() not storing vector_store

Tags: llama-index

`index.storage_context.persist()` is not storing the vector_store and creating the`vector_store.json` file

[image]

When I try to load from disk and run `sc2 = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir='./storage')`, i get the following error:

`No existing llama_index.vector_stores.simple found at ./storage/vector_store.json, skipping load.`

Not sure if this information is relevant, but there is only 1 document in my **documents** directory for embedding

Full Code:

with open('KPMGOutlook/kpmgoutlook.text', 'w') as file: file.write(kpmg_text)

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('KPMGOutlook').load_data()

vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection)
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store,persist_dir='storage')

index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, storage_context=storage_context)

index.storage_context.persist()

query_engine = index.as_query_engine()

#Querying document. this works fine
r = query_engine.query("Which economy has the most positive outlook?")
print(r)

#This line gives me the error
`sc2 = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir='./storage')`

Comment: Facing the same issue when using AWS S3 as the storage location

Answer (score 0):

Check this LlamaIndex [documentation](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/understanding/storing/storing.html#:%7E:text=Important%3A%20if%20you%20had%20initialized%20your%20index%20with%20a%20custom%20ServiceContext%20object%2C%20you%20will%20need%20to%20pass%20in%20the%20same%20ServiceContext%20during%20load_index_from_storage%2C%20or%20have%20it%20set%20as%20the%20global%20service%20context.)

It says that you have to give a reference to your ServiceContext object if you had initialized your index with a custom ServiceContext object.

Hope this solves your issue.